# Scale an image (making bigger) adding anti-alias with GD library

Tags: php, image, gd

I have a piece of code that takes an image as input and does a resize (scaling up, making it **bigger**). Input image does not contain any anti-alias, it means that it has sharp borders and corners. 
I want this scaling procedure to add anti-alias to have smooth borders and edges, like some graphic programs do (for example paint.NET, if I make the image bigger, anti-alias is automatically added).
How can I do that?

Here is my code

```
private function resize($source_path, $dest_path, $dest_w, $dest_h)
{
    $source = imagecreatefrompng($source_path);
    $source_w = imagesx($source);
    $source_h = imagesy($source);

    $output = imagecreatetruecolor($dest_w, $dest_h);
    imagealphablending($output, false);
    $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($output, 0, 0, 0, 127);
    imagefilledrectangle($output, 0, 0, $dest_w, $dest_h, $transparent);
    imagesavealpha($output, true);

    if (imagecopyresampled($output, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $dest_w, $dest_h, $source_w, $source_h)) {
        if (imagepng($output, $dest_path)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Thank you for any help.

EDIT: i tried to add interpolation

```
imagesetinterpolation($output,IMG_BICUBIC);
```

but nothing changed.

Comment: Can you show pics of what's happening currently? In my experience, any resizing with a true colour output, via `imagecopyresampled`, automatically results in anti-aliasing.

Comment: I can't upload images... due to validation problems, there is some bug in the editor.
Anyway, the result is exactly the same image, scaled, with no anti-alias at all

Comment: I mean upload images to your SO question of what's happening, otherwise we're just sort of guessing.